# Objects do not contain definition for 'xxx' - Microsoft tutorial

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, entity-framework-core

I am following along with an ASP.Net core tutorial on the Microsoft website: "Get Started with Entity Framework Core in an ASP.NET MVC web app".

The tutorial suggests that I enter the following code into my Program.cs file, in order to seed the database on application startup, and then dispose the context when the seed method is done.

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
     var host = CreateWebHostBuilder(args).Build();

    using (var scope = host.Services.CreateScope())
    {
        var services = scope.ServiceProvider;
        try
        {
            var context = services.GetRequiredService<SchoolContext>();
            DbInitializer.Initialize(context);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            var logger = services.GetRequiredService<ILogger<Program>>();
            logger.LogError(ex, "An error occurred while seeding the database.");
        }
    }

    host.Run();
}
```

However, both the 'Build' functions and the 'Initialize' functions are highlighted in red - and I get the error message "'object' does not contain a definition for 'Build' and no accessible extension method could be found", and a similar error message for Initialize.

Is there a 'using' clause that's missing somewhere here, or anything else that I really ought to be including?

Comment: Have you compared the ASP.NET Core (and EF Core possibly) version that you're using with the ones in the tutorial?

Comment: What is your version of asp.net core?And could you please share your `CreateWebHostBuilder` method and `Initialize` method?

Answer (score 0):

You could be missing a Nuget package - Check to confirm EFCore is installed from Nuget Package Manager on Visual Studio. If you're not using Visual Studio you can use the Package Manager CLI. You can check if your project references EFCore or not by taking a look at the csproj file, usually at the root folder of the project.

If the above doesn't help, then you're probably(most likely) missing a using statement.
Something like:

`using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;`

Finally, you might have created the project with a wrong version of .NET Core, Check properly as @Camilo Terevinto commented above